# NSImageView setImage causing NSView not correctly initialized

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm writing a networking program which sends an image from an iPhone to a Mac. I have the connection going fine, and passing data alright, but my problem is when I have the image sent over I try to display it and get the following warning:

> NSImageView(0x101321fd0) - NSView not correctly initialized. Did you
>   forget to call super?

Here is the code, it's the "setImage" command throwing the error.

This is my first major venture into Objective-C, I'm worried I messed up something with the xib but I can't be sure.

```
imageView = [NSImageView alloc];
[imageView setImage:theImage];

NSLog(@"Should be able to see image now..");
```

If this is too vague for a direct answer then any tips, references or tutorials you can guide me to would be very welcome.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to init the imageView.

```
 imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's gotten rid of the error. My image still isn't showing though, but that's probably a different issue. Thanks again!